# About how to configure karate with Http and ssl in one project

Tags: karate

I have one Karate project which including test Client Http apis and our internal webservices (using SSL). So I don't know how to set configuration in Karate.js file.
e.g.

> 1> karate.configure('proxy',  { uri: 'http://clientapiaddress',
>   username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx' }); 2> karate.configure('ssl',
>   {keyStore: ' xxx.p12', keyStorePassword: 'xxx'});

When I run feature which is testing internal web services, always get error

> "DNS_Fail" as: " The host name resolution (DNS lookup) for this host
>   name (   ) has failed. The
>   Internet address may be misspelled or obsolete, the host
>   (  ) may be temporarily
>   unavailable, or the DNS server may be unresponsive. "

Thanks

Comment: you may need some patience for SSL, please search previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+ssl

Answer (score 1):

you can do  * configure ssl = true as your background step